# how to avoid safety null

Tags: flutter, dart

in this class while declaring the constructor Repository i get this error 'Non-nullable instance field '_database' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'' i added late but it doesn't work the same error while declaring the static Database _database .
this is the class Repository

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:todo/repositories/database_connection.dart';
class Repository {
  DatabaseConnection _databaseConnection;

  Repository() {
    _databaseConnection = DatabaseConnection();
  }

  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await _databaseConnection.setDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  insertData(table, data) async {
    var connection = await database;
    return await connection.insert(table,data)
  }
```

and this is the DatabaseConnection

```
class DatabaseConnection {
  setDatabase() async {
    var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var path = join(directory.path, 'db_todo_sqflite');
    var database =
        await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreateDatabase);
    return database;
  }

  _onCreateDatabase(Database database, int version) async {
    await database.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE categories(id INTEGER KEY , name TEXT , descrption TEXT");
  }
}
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Adding `late` makes sense *only* if you can guarantee to never access the variable before it's used.  Since your code does `if (_database != null)` to initialize `_database` lazily, it must be nullable instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database itself is nullable, so you add a ?

```
static Database? _database;
```

That makes the _database nullable, but in your getter you are returning a non nullable instance of Database.
The nullable instance would be `Database?`

```dart
Future<Database?> get database async {
  ...
}
```

If you are sure that the _database is initialized, and can't be null at that point you return the value, and tell dart that this value is never null.

```dart
  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;
    _database = await _databaseConnection.setDatabase();
    return _database!;
  }
```

Note the "!" at the `return _database!`

See also https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

And https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#unchecked_use_of_nullable_value

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because

static Database _database is no nullable
Change the code to

> static Database? _database

Comment: yes i tried this but i still have the same error in constructor and  in the function Future<Database> get database async i get  a new error   A value of type 'Database?' can't be returned from the function 'database' because it has a return type of 'Future<Database>'

Comment: yes and by adding !  to return await connection!.insert(table, data); i don't have problem  but it is the same with the constructor how can i do to avoid null safetly

Comment: I think if you don't want null safety at all you have to downgrade dart sdk below version 2.12

Answer (score 0):

thank all for the response
this how i correct the code
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:todo/repositories/database_connection.dart';

```
class Repository {
  DatabaseConnection? _databaseConnection;

  Repository() {
    _databaseConnection = DatabaseConnection();
  }

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database?> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await _databaseConnection!.setDatabase();
    return _database! ;
  }

  insertData(table, data) async {
    var connection = await database;
    return await connection!.insert(table, data);
  }
}
```

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, you can mark it as correct, so that others will quickly find the solution to your problem in case they get the same

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the `late` modifier:

`late DatabaseConnection _databaseConnection;`

Just make sure you set this variable before you try to use it.